# How to merge two functions with same conditions?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I quickly wrote the below class for this question.

I'm looking for a way to merge `addFruit()` with `removeFruit()` to reduce the code.

They both use identical conditions but just different function call at the end.

**My Code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class MyClass
{
public:
    void addFruit(const std::string &str, int count)
    {
        if (str == "apples")
            addToVec(apples, count);
        else if (str == "oranges")
            addToVec(oranges, count);
        else if (str == "lemons")
            addToVec(lemons, count);
        else if (str == "melons")
            addToVec(melons, count);
        else if (str == "bananas")
            addToVec(bananas, count);
        else
            std::cout << "Unknown Fruit : " << str << '\n';
    }
    void removeFruit(const std::string &str)
    {
        if (str == "apples")
            removeFromVec(apples);
        else if (str == "oranges")
            removeFromVec(oranges);
        else if (str == "lemons")
            removeFromVec(lemons);
        else if (str == "melons")
            removeFromVec(melons);
        else if (str == "bananas")
            removeFromVec(bananas);
        else
            std::cout << "Unknown Fruit : " << str << '\n';
    }
private:
    void addToVec(std::vector<int> &vec, int count)
    {
        vec.push_back(count);
    }
    void removeFromVec(std::vector<int> &vec)
    {
        vec.pop_back();
    }
    std::vector<int> apples;
    std::vector<int> oranges;
    std::vector<int> lemons;
    std::vector<int> melons;
    std::vector<int> bananas;
};
```

Any clever way to nicely merge the two functions so I can reduce the code?

Comment: Pass an instance of `std::function` as a parameter. That holds either `removeFromVec` or `addFromVec`. The different arity of the two functions is a complication.

Comment: Surely  `else if (str == "oranges") addToVec(apples, count);` should be `else if (str == "oranges") addToVec(oranges, count);` etc. etc. Kind of important to get that right if you want a meaningful answer to your question.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for not having a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>` data member instead of five separate `std::vector` instances?

Comment: @lubgr I made the example just for this question. I agree your suggestion could be better.

Comment: As is already mentioned by @Bathsheba, how about creating std::array of std::function. Something like std::array<std::function<void(std::string, int)>, 2> = {addToVec, removeFromVec}. And then pass an index to function which can use this index into array to call the corresponding function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make an additional function e.g. `determineTargetVector(const std::string &str)` which returns the corresponding vector, where you want to insert/remove an element, so you have no redundant conditions. Also its nice to have only a single reponsibility for each function.

For example:

```
std::vector<int> *determineTargetVector(const std::string &str)
{
    if (str == "apples")
        return &apples;
    else if (str == "oranges")
        return &oranges;
    else if (str == "lemons")
        .
        .
        .
    else
        //something invalid, to check for in superior function
        return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution might be to use a `std::map` for those vectors:

```
std::map<std::string,std::vector<int>> fruitVecs;
```

The key values of the map would be `"apples"`, `"oranges"`, `"bananas"` etc.

Thus you can easily access the corresponding vector for any operation through the map.

Answer (score 2):

A code that selects the vector to be used and then perform the action can be used :

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void addFruit(const std::string &str, int count)
    {
        auto vec = selectVector(str);
        if(vec != nullptr)
            addToVec(*vec, count);
        else
            std::cout << "Unknown Fruit : " << str << '\n';
    }
    void removeFruit(const std::string &str)
    {
        auto vec = selectVector(str);
        if(vec != nullptr)
            removeFromVec(*vec);
        else
            std::cout << "Unknown Fruit : " << str << '\n';
    }
private:

    std::vector<int> *selectVector(const std::string &str)
    {
        if (str == "apples")
            return &apples;
        else if (str == "oranges")
            return &oranges;
        else if (str == "lemons")
            return &lemons;
        else if (str == "melons")
            return &melons;
        else if (str == "bananas")
            return &bananas;
        else
            return nullptr;
    }

    void addToVec(std::vector<int> &vec, int count)
    {
        vec.push_back(count);
    }
    void removeFromVec(std::vector<int> &vec)
    {
        vec.pop_back();
    }
    std::vector<int> apples;
    std::vector<int> oranges;
    std::vector<int> lemons;
    std::vector<int> melons;
    std::vector<int> bananas;
};
```

Comment: Accepted, a little duplication is still there. The method you suggested std::function can avoid that too.

Comment: I'd use a map to define the lookup but otherwise yes

Answer (score 2):

What about below solution. That will also allow you add/remove known fruits easily by adding/removing line in constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        allowedFruits["apples"] = {};
        allowedFruits["oranges"] = {};
        allowedFruits["lemons"] = {};
        allowedFruits["melons"] = {};
        allowedFruits["bananas"] = {};
    }
    void addFruit(const std::string &str, int count)
    {
        auto it = allowedFruits.find(str);
        if(it != MyClass::allowedFruits.end()){
            it->second.push_back(count);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Unknown Fruit : " << str << '\n';
        }
    }
    void removeFruit(const std::string &str)
    {
        auto it = allowedFruits.find(str);
        if(it != allowedFruits.end()){
            // my be some check here
            it->second.pop_back();
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Unknown Fruit : " << str << '\n';
        }
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string,std::vector<int>> allowedFruits;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the interface you could do it like this:

```
std::vector<int>& pickVector(std::string str) {
    // put all the switch here and return a reference to the correct vector
}

void addFruit(const std::string &str, int count)
{
   addToVec(pickVector(str),count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go a little functionnal by passing the function to apply.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class MyClass
{
public:
    void addFruit(const std::string &str, int count)
    {
        searchAndApplyHelper(str, std::bind(&MyClass::addToVec, *this, std::placeholders::_1, count));
    }
    void removeFruit(const std::string &str)
    {
        searchAndApplyHelper(str, std::bind(&MyClass::removeFromVec, *this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

private:

    template <class Func>
    void searchAndApplyHelper(const std::string str, Func f)
    {
        if (str == "apples")
            f(apples);
        else if (str == "oranges")
            f(oranges);
        else if (str == "lemons")
            f(lemons);
        else if (str == "melons")
            f(melons);
        else if (str == "bananas")
            f(bananas);
        else
            std::cout << "Unknown Fruit : " << str << '\n';
    }

    void addToVec(std::vector<int> &vec, int count)
    {
        vec.push_back(count);
    }
    void removeFromVec(std::vector<int> &vec)
    {
        vec.pop_back();
    }
    std::vector<int> apples;
    std::vector<int> oranges;
    std::vector<int> lemons;
    std::vector<int> melons;
    std::vector<int> bananas;
};
```

I did it with a template but you could use `std::function` as well.

Comment: A lambda would be prettier

Comment: Like this ? `searchAndApplyHelper(str, [&](auto & str) { addToVec(str, count); });` Yep, it is :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void addFruit(const std::string &str, int count)
    {
        doToFruit(str, [&](std::vector<int> &vec){ addToVec(vec, count); });
    }
    void removeFruit(const std::string &str)
    {
        doToFruit(str, [&](std::vector<int> &vec){ removeFromVec(vec); });
    }
private:
    template<typename Callable>
    void doToFruit(const std::string &str, const Callable &func)
    {
        std::pair<const char*, std::vector<int>&> fruits[] = {
            {"apple", apples}, {"oranges", oranges}, {"lemons", lemons},
            {"melons", melons}, {"bananas", bananas}
        };
        for (auto i : fruits)
            if (str == i.first)
                return func(i.second);
        std::cout << "Unknown Fruit : " << str << '\n';
    }
    void addToVec(std::vector<int> &vec, int count)
    {
        vec.push_back(count);
    }
    void removeFromVec(std::vector<int> &vec)
    {
        vec.pop_back();
    }
    std::vector<int> apples;
    std::vector<int> oranges;
    std::vector<int> lemons;
    std::vector<int> melons;
    std::vector<int> bananas;
};
```

You can use [pointer to members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) if you want better performance:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void addFruit(const std::string &str, int count)
    {
        doToFruit(str, [&](std::vector<int> &vec){ addToVec(vec, count); });
    }
    void removeFruit(const std::string &str)
    {
        doToFruit(str, [&](std::vector<int> &vec){ removeFromVec(vec); });
    }
private:
    template<typename Callable>
    void doToFruit(const std::string &str, const Callable &func)
    {
        auto iFound = fruits.find(str);
        if (iFound != fruits.end())
            return func(this->*(iFound->second));
        std::cout << "Unknown Fruit : " << str << '\n';
    }
    void addToVec(std::vector<int> &vec, int count)
    {
        vec.push_back(count);
    }
    void removeFromVec(std::vector<int> &vec)
    {
        vec.pop_back();
    }
    std::vector<int> apples;
    std::vector<int> oranges;
    std::vector<int> lemons;
    std::vector<int> melons;
    std::vector<int> bananas;
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int> MyClass::*> fruits;
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int> MyClass::*> MyClass::fruits = {
    {"apple", &MyClass::apples}, {"oranges", &MyClass::oranges},
    {"lemons", &MyClass::lemons}, {"melons", &MyClass::melons},
    {"bananas", &MyClass::bananas}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using C++17 you could use optional arguments:

```
void addRemoveFruit(const std::string &str, std::optional<int> count = std::nullopt)
{
    if (str == "apples")
        addRemoveVec(apples, count);
    else if (str == "oranges")
        addRemoveVec(oranges, count);
    else if (str == "lemons")
        addRemoveVec(lemons, count);
    else if (str == "melons")
        addRemoveVec(melons, count);
    else if (str == "bananas")
        addRemoveVec(bananas, count);
    else
        std::cout << "Unknown Fruit : " << str << '\n';
}
```

and:

```
void addRemoveVec(std::vector<int> &vec, std::optional<int> count = std::nullopt)
{
    if(count.has_value()) {
        vec.push_back(count.value());
    } else {
        vec.pop_back();
    }
}
```

This way existing calls to `addFruit`/`removeFruit` only need to be changed to `addRemoveFruit` without having to change the parameters passed.

Comment: what if someone wants to add 0 apples?

Comment: @user463035818 Updated

Comment: tbh I still dont like it that much. YMMV, but I thing using the absence of a parameter to decide on what the method does opens the door to lots of confusion.

Comment: @user463035818 I understand that, my initial reasoning was to try to go along with something that was relatively straight forward to make if fit somewhat with the code that was provided (hence just using a default value of 0), and the only real advantage of this is that function parameters already in place don't need to be changed, it would better be done by leaving `addFruit` and `removeFruit` and then having them call an appropriate function instead, but again I wanted to try and keep it similar to the existing code, rather than adding `map`s, ptrs etc.

Comment: This is not very expressive

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure, but the goal was simply to *"merge the two functions so I can reduce the code"* (I took it as `add` and `remove` functions), there's plenty more could be done to improve it further which I think have been better covered in other answers

Answer (score -1):

To stick with your pattern of multiple distinct vectors, I'd recommend using an internal enum that decides the method, while the choice of the vector can be done in one place:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void addFruit(const std::string &str, int count)
    {
        addOrRemoveFruit(str, count, Method::ADD);
    }
    void removeFruit(const std::string &str)
    {
        addOrRemoveFruit(str, 0, Method::REMOVE);
    }

private:
    enum class Method
    {
        ADD,
        REMOVE
    };

    void addOrRemoveFruit(const std::string &str, int count, Method method)
    {
        if (str == "apples")
            addOrRemoveFruitImpl(apples, count, method);
        else if (str == "oranges")
            addOrRemoveFruitImpl(oranges, count, method);
        else if (str == "lemons")
            addOrRemoveFruitImpl(lemons, count, method);
        else if (str == "melons")
            addOrRemoveFruitImpl(melons, count, method);
        else if (str == "bananas")
            addOrRemoveFruitImpl(bananas, count, method);
        else
            std::cout << "Unknown Fruit : " << str << '\n';
    }

    void addOrRemoveFruitImpl(std::vector<int> &vec, int count, Method method)
    {
        if (method == Method::ADD)
             vec.push_back(count);
        else
             vec.pop_back();
    }

    std::vector<int> apples;
    std::vector<int> oranges;
    std::vector<int> lemons;
    std::vector<int> melons;
    std::vector<int> bananas;
};
```

However even better would be to use a map:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void addFruit(const std::string &str, int count)
    {
        fruits[str].push_back(count);
    }
    void removeFruit(const std::string &str)
    {
        if (fruits.count(str) > 0)
            fruits[str].pop_back();
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> fruits;
};
```

Comment: @downvoter: I am always eager to learn and improve, please let me know what's wrong with this answer :)

Comment: didnt downvote, though overloading to do something different isnt nice imho. I'd rather call it `do_add...` or `_impl`

Comment: @user463035818 Absolutely right, that was an oversight.

Comment: @user463035818 I agree. Adding more attributes & enums, reduces the LOC and redundancy but increases the complexity/readability of the code. In my opinion, at the first glance on an boxed problem like this its obvious, but it isn't well scalable. (Only personal opinion)